# Btn are not getting the color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button with the following code, but the CSS below is not working
i.e. the color and size is not changing

**CSS**:

```css
.btn-default .act-buttons{
    background-color: black!important;
    color: white!important;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default act-buttons" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you intended `.btn-default, .act-buttons`?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak-Btn-defult I guess is coming from bootstrap so Im not sure...

Comment: I suggest he wants `.btn-default.act-buttons` with no space between

Comment: Try .btn-default.act-buttons without space between. With space it works completly different.

Comment: @Paulie_D I already try to avoid the space in the CSS file like you suggest but it was not solve the problem..

Comment: Then we need a JSfiddle to experiment with.

Comment: No, look at @Sharlike comment, add a comma http://www.bootply.com/vml1xlUdIj

Comment: @Paulie_D-in the fiddle its working http://jsfiddle.net/JM7Cb/2/ ,what can be the problem?

Comment: @Sharlike-this is the answer please provide it as answer and I close the question,can you explain why I need to add ',' ?

Comment: @HolgerTans added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your most recent html...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default act-buttons" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this css (note the lack of a space in `.btn-default.act-buttons`):

```
.btn-default.act-buttons{
    background-color: black!important;
    color: white!important;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

This will target any element with both classes `btn-default` and `act-buttons`

---

`.btn-default .act-buttons` would target a parent element with the class `btn-default` which contains a child element with the class `act-buttons`

`.btn-default,.act-buttons` would target any element with either of the classes `btn-default` or `act-buttons`

Answer (score 0):

your css is targeting any class named act-buttons which is inside an element which has a class btn-default

you could change it to

.btn-default, .act-buttons{...}

or

.btn-default.act-buttons{...} // no space between classes

Answer (score 0):

### Overview of [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors):

First things first, make sure you're using the right selector:

- **[Descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)**: `.btn-default .act-buttons`
  Will find any elements with the class `act-buttons` that are descendants of an element with the class `btn-default`
- **And Selector**: `.btn-default.act-buttons`
  Will find any elements that match both class selectors, meaning any element that has `class="btn-default act-buttons"`
- **Or Selector**: `.btn-default, act-buttons`
  Will find any elements that **either** have a class of `btn-default` **or**  a class of `act-buttons`

### Also, check that...

- The html element has access to the selector
- You've applied your custom styles *after* the bootstrap style sheet

  - You should always try to override standard styles with your own

    - then you don't need `!important`
- Finally, make sure you're using `act-buttons` or `action-buttons` consistently

### [Here's a working demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLeLL/)

```css
.btn.act-buttons{
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

@KyleMit's is the answer you'll learn the most from, and specifically, you want to pay attention to his note on the And Selector:"`btn-default.act-buttons` will find any elements that match both class selectors, meaning any element that has `class="btn-default act-buttons`"

So, using the And Selector, you should use

```
.btn-default.act-buttons{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
```

like here: **http://www.bootply.com/bFjCr8eQlY**

*ps - your height and width will need it's own fixing unless what you put in the button is exactly the right size, but that's another issue.*

Answer (score -1):

well try this

```
<div class="form">

    <input class="field button2" id="submit" type="button" value="Save"/>

    </div>
```

and in your css

```
.button {
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font: 13px sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000
}
.button:hover { background-color: #46000D; }


input.button2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff
}
input.button2:hover { background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; }
```

it will look better, i hope i helped you :-D